# angular rc1: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot find default outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I really should paste source-code here, but I do not know which part of those 300 lines in my component I should show you.

Maybe the error-message "EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot find default outlet" has a general solution to it? Am I missing some parameter or tag?

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in you root component? Or do you reference `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` somewhere else besides the root component?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am using a subsomponent in a component, and I have <router-outlet></router-outlet> in every component (in the corresponding html-template-files)

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: in pluckr eveything works fine, it must be something burried deep inside the project (it was set it up with angular-cli). It only happens when I navigate to the url which loads the subcomponent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- add the `<router-outlet>` where the router expects it ;-)
- ensure you don't provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` more than once in your application (either **only** at the root component or **only** in `bootstrap()`)
- don't add `*ngIf*` to the `<router-outlet>` or to a parent of `<router-outlet>`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8539

Answer (score 3):

I found it:

The component hosting the subcomponent needs to declare

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
```

otherwise the  is not recognized, as it seems.